# in android public class ImageDownlod extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap

Tags: android

in class ImageDownlod  give me error when using void in second var...

error in using void

**error here in void**

```
           public class ImageDownlod extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap>   
            {


                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                        HttpsURLConnection connection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream inputStream= connection.getInputStream();
                        Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        return mybitmap;
                    }

                    catch (MalformedURLException e)
                    {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```